# How to translate dynamic content (from database using api call) using ng-translate

Tags: node.js, angularjs, localization, translation

I am using ng-translate for localisation in my project. It is working perfect for static content but I am not getting how to translate dynamic content which is coming from database (by making api calls).

I have layout page and index page which extends layout page. This index page also contain dynamic menu which is shown on top. I have also one menu for selection of languages. Now when i am selecting language, it is translating the static content on layout, index, partial view and menus. My question is how I will make my dynamic content like menus item, content on layout page, content on partial view page to be translated automatically ?

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some example of how you index page looks like with the dynamic data?